# Podio External ID change

Tags: podio

We use an external setup that sends information on our orders into Podio and from there we manage them. We have had an issue with our Email field and it's lead to the External ID 'email' being lost (we are up to email-6' now before realising the issue). Is it possible to reset/restore the External ID to be 'Email' instead of 'Email-6' and if so could you please point to how we can do it. The developers we use don't work with us anymore so it's a bit of a nightmare to sort out. We are reasonably tech savvy but not wiz kids by any stretch of the imagination. I've copied below what our old developers said:

"What I'm pretty sure is your case, is that you have deleted the original Email field from the template, and now you are trying to put it back. The problem is that, only by appearance, you have a single Email field in your template, but when Fabnami is sending the data, the collected customer email is attached to the field with external ID "email", not the one you have only labeled as Email. The result is that podio will exhume the deleted field and will display it using the last labels it has. In your case there will be the original field with label "Email" and ExternalID "email" plus a second empty field with label "Email" but different External ID."

I hope you can help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Each time, when the field get created, external_id get created in parallel(1 to 1 mapping). If you delete the field the external id get deleted along with that. You can't reset the external id "email" to "email-6".

There is a option to recover the first deleted field "Email" -> external is id "email", but with the recovery payment.

Answer (score 0):

Each time, when the field get created, external_id get created in parallel. If you delete the field the external id get deleted along with that. You can't reset the external id "email" to "email-6".

There is a option to recover the first deleted field "Email" -> external is id "email", but with the recovery payment.